# gd2 not showing in phpinfo, is showing in php -i

Tags: gd, php, gd2

I'm trying to get the gd2 extension to work on a WAMP stack (Win7(x64), Apache 2.4, PHP 5.3.26)

I've enabled extension=php_gd2.dll in php.ini and restarted Apache.

I believe my extension directory is reachable as I'm able to load other extensions (eg., curl, mbstring, etc.,) from the same location.

Oddly, php -i lists gd as enabled, but there's no mention of it in phpinfo():

```
gd

GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.4.10
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 8
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.2.50
WBMP Support => enabled
XPM Support => enabled
libXpm Version => 30411
XBM Support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 0 => 0
```

Any ideas?

Will update if I find a solution, and many thanks in advance!

Nao

Comment: gd_info();

Produces a fatal error, it's definitely not working.

Comment: SOLVED:

Silly me.

I had enabled php_gd2.dll in a copy of php.ini in my PHP installation directory (c:\php), without realising I had a copy of php.ini in c:\Windows.

The copy in c:\Windows was the one being loaded but did not contain the uncommented ...

    extension=php_gd2.dll

... directive, and that's why it wasn't working.