# mbstring missing from phpinfo but enabled in php.ini

Tags: php, apache

Similar to this question: [gd2 not showing in phpinfo, is showing in php -i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150860/gd2-not-showing-in-phpinfo-is-showing-in-php-i)

I have the same problem with `mbstring`. I enabled it in my `php.ini` (which is *the only `php.ini` **on my whole system** - and yes, I checked **and** double checked that!*), but when I open up `phpinfo` on my Apache, mbstring is missing. If I do `php -i`, all of the `mbstring` data is showing up nicely.

Apache (`phpinfo.php`)

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path       C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File               F:\PHP\5.4\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
Additional .ini files parsed            (none)
```

Apache (`index.php`)

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_get_info() 
in F:\Apache\httpd-2.4\htdocs\index.php on line 2
```

PHP CLI:

```
F:\Apache\httpd-2.4\htdocs> php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         F:\PHP\5.4\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

F:\Apache\httpd-2.4\htdocs> php index.php
array(14) {
  ["internal_encoding"]=>
  string(10) "ISO-8859-1"
  ["http_output"]=>
  string(4) "pass"
  ["http_output_conv_mimetypes"]=>
  string(31) "^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)"
  ["func_overload"]=>
  int(0)
  ["func_overload_list"]=>
  string(11) "no overload"
  ["mail_charset"]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
  ["mail_header_encoding"]=>
  string(6) "BASE64"
  ["mail_body_encoding"]=>
  string(6) "BASE64"
  ["illegal_chars"]=>
  int(0)
  ["encoding_translation"]=>
  string(3) "Off"
  ["language"]=>
  string(7) "neutral"
  ["detect_order"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "ASCII"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "UTF-8"
  }
  ["substitute_character"]=>
  int(63)
  ["strict_detection"]=>
  string(3) "Off"
}
```

What is happening here? Bugs in `apache`/`phpinfo()`?

Comment: SAPI-mode php (e.g. "in webserver") uses a completely different .ini file than CLI php. You need to run `phpinfo`() from within your webserver and it'll tell you where that .ini file(s) is.

Comment: I stated what `phphinfo()` shows me right at the top of the question. It is the exact same file that CLI uses.

Comment: Have you restarted the web-server?

Comment: Yes, multiple times - as well as windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that when PHP is loaded via apache, the `extension_dir` is apparently read **relative to the apache server root dir**.

But, starting from command line, it is **read relative to the PHP root dir**.

Thus, despite it being the same loaded `php.ini`, because I set the extension dir as `ext` instead of `F:\PHP\5.4\ext`, apache (or rather: PHP) searched for it in `F:\Apache\2.4\ext`, which it didn't find for obvious reasons.

Setting the `extension_dir` to an absolute folder solved the issue. Now apache and cmd both load the exact same configuration, including all extensions (which is exactly how I wanted it).

Comment: I did not find something about this behaviour in the PHP or Apache docs, so if anyone does, please post it as a comment.

Comment: I just spend 4 hours on this issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: @freshfelicio Yeah, it really is a weird thing if you are not told about it anywhere :D

Comment: Confirmed... setting the extension_dir in the php.ini with an absolute path resolved the same issue for me.