# PHP mbstring doesn't work with Apache on Windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, php-extension, mbstring

I have to get PHP 5.4 (32 bit, TS) with mbstring running with Apache 2.4 (32 bit) on Windows. In my httpd.conf I set this:

```
PHPIniDir "c:/php54"
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php54/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

And in my php.ini:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
...
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

Now, when I execute `php -m` it correctly says that mbstring is loaded:

```
...
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
...
```

And `php -i` spits out a section about mbstring:

```
mbstring

Multibyte Support => enabled
Multibyte string engine => libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation => disabled
libmbfl version => 1.3.2
...
```

But, when I have a simple index.php with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` there is no word about mbstring, even though it says the correct php.ini was used.

When I change index.php to `<?php echo mb_convert_case("hello world", MB_CASE_UPPER); ?>` it errors with

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_convert_case() in C:\Apache24x86\htdocs\index.php on line 1
```

I can run the exact same script with PHP CLI `php index.php` and it correctly prints `HELLO WORLD`.

Why is mbstring working in php.exe, but not in Apache? Of course I restarted Apache numerous times and even my whole PC.

Comment: maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25432880/5297359

Comment: The Web SAPI and the CLI SAPI typically have different php.ini files, you need to make sure that you've changed the appropriate one.... if you're running `php -m` from the command line, and see that it's installed, then you've probably only enabled it for the CLI SAPI

Comment: Maybe you have a different config file being loaded for CLI as you do for the web server.  Also you have to restart the web server for a number of config changes to take effect.  Look at the ini-file portion of phpinfo from both the commandline and the phpinfo page you set up

Comment: Also, I think support for PHP 5.4 ended with the release of PHP 7.  You might want to look into upgrading to at least 5.6

Comment: @MarkBaker I can see in phpinfo() that it is the correct ini file and I also set PHPIniDir.

Comment: @swidmannn this was the right tip. Thank you. If you want to post this as answer I can accept it.

Comment: @GordonM I restarted and everything. It's the correct ini. I know it is old and unsupported, but my client is still running it, so I have to get my development environment setup before I can test if it breaks with PHP7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mbstring missing from phpinfo but enabled in php.ini](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414785/mbstring-missing-from-phpinfo-but-enabled-in-php-ini)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it with a cmd command

1. Turn off all the apache services
2. Run cmd as administrator
3. Go to the bin folder of apache, in my case, with the command `cd C:\Apache24\bin`
4. create a symbolic link with the file php.ini with the command `bin>mklink php.ini C:\php\php.ini`

Example:

[image: cmd example]

I hope this will help you solve your problem.

Comment: I had the same issue. My php dir is on D:. So I opened a cmd as administrator and went to C:\ and typed `mklink /D php D:\php.inì` and that resolved my issues