# the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system

Tags: php, laravel, mbstring

my error message that I am getting from the composer is:
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
 Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.4.28 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.28].
    - laravel/framework v5.4.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 5.7.21 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.7.21].
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.21 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - laravel/framework v5.4.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/tinker v1.0.1 requires illuminate/console ~5.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.28].
    - Installation request for laravel/tinker v1.0.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/tinker[v1.0.1].
```

I have tried uncommenting the extension=php_mbstring.dll but it still raises the error. I have tried to change the extension_dir in the "php.ini" and it gives an error. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Had the same problem yesterday, solved it by installing it. But first you should specify which os you are running. For me it was centOS: `yum install   php70w-mbstring` but for most common: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471633/cannot-initialize-mbstring-with-php-7

Comment: Have you set the environment variable for php in your system?

Comment: I am using windows and I have tried to uncomment the extension=php_mbstring.dll unfortunately it does not work for some reason

Comment: I have set in the environment variables the paths to ...\Composer\vendor\bin,
...\Git\cmd,
...\Git\bin,
...\ComposerSetup\bin

Comment: I have tried most of the "stack overflow" pages, it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: I have just added ...\PHP\vendor\composer,
...\PHP\ext to the environment variable and its brings the same error

Comment: It isn't clear whether you're reporting a pure Laravel or Composer problem or the mbstring extension is actually not installed despite your efforts. Does it show up when you run `php -m`?

Comment: it doesn't show this is the output bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mcrypt
mysqlnd
pcre
PDO
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

Comment: Windows with `IIS`? `XAMPP`, `WAMP`, `MAMP` [other?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_server_software#Operating_system_support)?

Comment: XAMPP is what i am using

Comment: which php version you are using? looks like you haven't set environment variable for PHP

Comment: 7.1.6 is my current php version in the command composer install and laravel new project_name i get the same error output as shown above

PHP 7.1.6 (cli) (built: Jun  8 2017 01:53:41) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 15, accepted):

-- EDIT BASED ON NEW INFORMATION --

Since this is Windows, re-installing PHP, enabling the extension in the PHP.INI file, and restarting the Webserver, should work.

-- PREVIOUS SOLUTION FOR LINUX --

You need to install mbstring for php.

Use:

```
 sudo apt-get install phpX.X-mbstring
```

Where X.X is your version number of PHP.

Comment: I am using windows with command prompt this is a Linux command which the cmd does not recognise

Comment: OK, if you uncommented the extension, did you restart the webserver?

Comment: I did, but on the php -m command I don't see the mbstring so, renstalling php and composer did not work

Comment: Perhaps see this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414785/mbstring-missing-from-phpinfo-but-enabled-in-php-ini/25432880#25432880

Comment: update your solution so I can mark it as a correct one I had a conflict on the version on the php in the composer so I reinstalled it using the PHP downloaded from the site and it worked

Answer (score 5):

Its worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
```

Comment: CentOS: yum install php-mbstring

Answer (score 3):

It works

sudo apt-get install php7.3-mbstring

sudo apt install php-xml

composer update